# Trying to install google assistant on my windows 10 laptop but I get this error after I try to use it

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-assistant-sdk

I am using the new sdk for the google assistant along with the new commands for it (`python -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.audio_helpers` and `python -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk`) it always passes the test but keeps coming up with this error when I try to use it.

`C:\Users\oliverdavison>python -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk

INFO:root:Connecting to embeddedassistant.googleapis.com

WARNING:root:Device config not found: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\oliverdavison\\AppData\\Roaming\\googlesamples-assistant\\device_config.json'

INFO:root:Registering device

ERROR:root:Option --device-model-id required when registering a device instance.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow [this guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/register-device) to use the [Actions console](http://console.actions.google.com) to register a device model id, after which you will use as a flag in your command line.

```
C:\Users\oliverdavison>python -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk \
  --device-model-id <my-device-model-id>
```

Comment: When following the link and the guide I get to a point where I have to select the device and there is no PC/windows computer etc. option there.

Comment: You just need to register a device and include that device model id as a flag. The device type doesn't matter, it can be a `light` or anything else.

Comment: Yeah ok, now I'm getting this. `python -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk \ --device-model-id <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>`    
`The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

Comment: Don't include the carats.